# Proper tool for installing engineered wood flooring

Tags: flooring, subfloor, engineered-flooring, nailing

Lauzon 3 1/4 planks, tongue-and-groove. To clarify, it's the stuff with 1/8" real wood on top. Over OSB sub-floor. This is all new construction. About 500 sf right now, but another 500 sf about 6 months from now.

1. If we use a brad nailer and tapping block, will we get a tight enough joint? (*Note, we have a flooring nailer, but it seems we can't use it with engineering flooring. One thing the flooring nailer ensures is a tight joint.*)
2. Is it worth buying a proper flooring nailer for engineered wood, given the amount we have to do, and my husband's 63-year-old knees? We'd have to order it online, neither Lowes nor HD carry them.
3. Also, any opinions on the problem of getting the correct angle on the nail, if we use the brad nailer. (*Obviously with a dedicated floor nailer that's not a problem*).

Comment: What do the instructions from the manufacturer say about installation? 500 sq ft is an investment, Right tool for the job is always the best advise.

Comment: Nothing much. I did look at the instructions, professional courtesy...

Comment: The flooring nailer I have has bottom plates that can be changed out for different thicknesses of flooring, besides having a add on plate to protect prefinished flooring.

Comment: What is the underlayment? If it is thicker than thick paper, or is "cushy" it will make for a squeaky floor

Comment: 1. Floor Muffler ultraseal. It's recommended for impact noise abatement under wood floor, so I can't see how it would make the floor squeak
2. The problem with the flooring nailer is that it uses thicker nails, made for hardwood. It won't take the smaller nails required to avoid destroying engineered wood.

Comment: Any engineered flooring I have seen has had a core or base of plywood with the 1/8" finish on top, like you described. Plywood has a lot less tendency to split that solid wood. Besides the fasteners I seen for floors are either 1/2" crown staples, or "T" nails that are quite thin. I don't think it would be an issue, unless the install guide does not recommend it. Other than that, the only engineered floor that was 3/8" thick, I had dealings with was set with narrow gauge (1/4") but I do not know if it was done all by staple gun or flooring stapler.

Comment: I agree with Jack on the flooring nailer. What is the mfg suggesting?

Comment: We bit the bullet and ordered a nailer that takes 18 guage. We are DIY, so we are already saving lots of money. The only drawback is the 1 week wait because we won't order from You Know Who with their prime delivery.

If I remember, I will post after we've installed, to let everyone know how it went.